# regex validating if string ends with specific set of words

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-substr

In a javascript code want to match a string with regex to return boolean (if string meets the requirement).

The string should end with `yes`, `no`, or `maybe` non-case-sensitive and can be wrapped with (or only at one side) a double-quote.  so any string that ends with `"Yes"`, `"yes"`, `yes`, `"YES"`, etc. is acceptable.

I have the following which is wrong. How should I construct the regex, or is it a good way in javascript?

```js
function test(){
var str =document.getElementById("str").value;  
const regex = /.*\"?[YES|NO|MAYBE]\"?$/gmi;
const result = new RegExp(regex).test(str);
console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="str" name="str" value=""/>
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="test()"/>
```

Comment: `[...]` is a character class, you need a grouping construct, `(...)` / `(?:...)`. `const regex = /"?(?:YES|NO|MAYBE)"?$/i` or `const regex = /(?:"(?:YES|NO|MAYBE)"|YES|NO|MAYBE)$/i`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry by that I meant etc

Comment: I see, but the main problem is still that you are using `[...]`, which is a character class. Note you [should avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results) `g` flag in patterns that you use in `RegExp#test`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot